# How to dynamically update other pages' content

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

New to programming here. I'm using Rails to create a web app that does reviews, but am having a little trouble figuring out where to start on this one particular part. I'd appreciate any and all help:

Let's say that on my homepage I want to have a top 10 list of restaurants. Beside each place there would be a score. If you were to click on the link to that restaurant, it would bring you to that restaurant's detail page where you can rate a number of different qualities. As users rate the place the score will update. How can I get that score and ranking to be reflected on my main homepage based on how users rate each place? Thinking this might have to be done with some Javascript (or is there a way to do this in Rails?). Thanks!

Comment: That is the reason we use databases. Whenever you render a "view" (homepage, restaurant view, etc.) all the information that is displayed and is not "static", it is extracted from the database, so, everytime you update a record in your database, it will be reflected in any page that use that same data.

Comment: What waclock said. Also, do you want it updated only when the user refreshes the page, or updated whenever a new score is added?

Comment: Ok, great. I'd like to have it updated whenever a visitor refreshes the page. Would any type of javascript be needed if on the homepage each place were also color coded based on score (for example, its row background was colored green for higher scores, red for lower scores)?

Comment: @wdace84 if you want to update the scores on refresh then you won't need anything else but if you want them to update automatically then you'll require ajax. For color coding you can simply apply different classes to restaurants and then style those classes with css

Comment: @user2675613 Thanks for the help. What if the color depended on their score (for example: if the score is > 90 then make the color green, but if the score is < 50 then make the color red)? Would this be done within rails (updating class background color based on the score in the database)?

Comment: no it's pure css you only need to use ruby for applying classes to that particular row. For example if for score <50 you want to use red class then you can do <div class="<%= 'red' if @score < 50 %>"></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pure answer to your question is you need [data persistence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data) - a place to centrally store data & render it in the view for the user.

It's funny why you should ask this question in the `Ruby on Rails` section - this is *exactly* what this framework is for, and I would question your competency if you didn't consider this

--

**Database**

Rails uses a central database to store your data. It uses the [MVC programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) to give you the ability to access that data wherever you require; allowing you to manipulate it as per your requirements:

[image]

Without detailing how to make your app from scratch, I'll give you the basic principle you should use:

```
#config/routes.rb
root "restaurants#index"
resources :restaurants

#app/controllers/restaurants_controller.rb
Class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController
   def index
       @restaurants = Restaurant.all
   end
end

#app/models/restaurant.rb
Class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :reviews
end

#app/models/review.rb
Class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :restaurant
end

#app/views/restaurants/index.html.erb
<% for restaurant in @restaurants do %>
    <%= restaurant.reviews.count %>
<% end %>
```

--

**Recommended Reading**

You'll be best reading the [Rails beginner guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running) on how to get this working properly. It's basically what Rails is for ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Only javascript is not enough.**

When website is loaded in user's browser, all information from database are loaded once, like html files. Even if you'll update your restaurant object using ajax or simple redirect_to :back method, there will be no change on other page or other browser.

To solve it, you could use something like **pusher** to send events each time when somebody will trigger an event in your app and receive this events on your home page. If functionality of your app isn't complicated, you can use your own push server like faye in your rails app. Here is reference to railscast about using it:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye?view=similar

Anyway, i prefer to use pusher every time when I need to add some realtime functionality in my app.

http://pusher.com/tutorials

And about voting process, the nice solutions for doing that is:

"twitter/activerecord-reputation-system"

If you don't want to use ajax which will update your voted restaurant page's content, you can add `vote` method in your controller with `redirect_to :back` . This instruction will redirect your app to new url and after finish whole method will redirect back to refreshed page with updated voting status.

```
def vote
  value = params[:type] == "up" ? 1 : -1
  @haiku = Haiku.find(params[:id])
  @haiku.add_or_update_evaluation(:votes, value, current_user)
  redirect_to :back, notice: "Thank you for voting!"
end
```

To refresh home page dynamically when other users will vote on restaurants, u should create a rake task which will update the information on the page based on updated database structure.